# how to make a custom ubuntu 11.10 64 bit installation DVD

Tags: 64-bit, android, custom-installer

i want to include some packages into Ubuntu,the packages i want to add are

1. ubuntu resticted extra(mp3 codecs,wifi drivers)
2. 32 bit libraries(ia32-lib)
3. kvm with gui(for virtualization/emulation of android tv SDK,and
   windows)
4. eclipse
5. gimp
6. java 6 JRE and JDK
7. android sdk(not available in USC and is not a package)
8. VLC
9. if possible updates
10. rhythmbox instead of banshee

i need this custom installation DVD to distribute to particpants of android workshop and also helps me for reinstalling the os in case of any broken desktop,and saving almost 200Mb of data usage everytime.

UPDATE:i have tried UCK,the package manager is not opening and returning error "there is no package manager",even though synaptic package mannager is available

Comment: Check this out -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd/49679#49679

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD/Persistence

http://uck.sourceforge.net/

http://homepage.mac.com/bner/iblog/B1570693677/C1271976503/E1448650622/index.html

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=858329

http://gicl.cs.drexel.edu/people/tjkopena/wiki/pmwiki.php?n=SWAT.UbuntuLiveCDCustomization

This is an endless list.Do one thing **first of all make sure that  you have all the required packages libraries (in the binary or the source code)**

then follow the steps on any of the sites to place them

***(Hey make sure that if you compile something that COMPILATION must be done on the customized system otherwise there maybe problem of cross compilers and others)***

Comment: i have .debs stored in a disc using aptoncd,on all links i find problem with adding packages...

Comment: ,many of the manuals are written for 9.04,and many changes occured since,so i am seeing for a manual/tutorial that has been done using 11.10 64 bit.I have tried UCK in 11.10(no result),and now i am trying UCK in 11.04